# Fastest way to populate an array?

Tags: python, algorithm, modulo

I want to populate an array of size n like this (a very big array):

```
1 for i = 1, (n/2)+1
```

```
2 for i = 2, 3, ... , (n/2)
```

```
0 for i = (n/2)+2, ... , n
```

Is the fastest way iterating through 0 to n and using an if statement and % for each one?

Like this:

```
array = []
for index in range(1,n):
    if index == 1 or (index % ((n/2)+1) == 0):
        array.append(1)
    if index == 2 or index == 3 or (index % (n/2) == 0):
        array.append(2)
    if (index % ((n/2)+2) == 0):
        array.append(0)
```

I have tried to think of other ways to do this but I have not come up with anything. I'm not a programmer by trade but I am not sure how else I would implement this.

Comment: None of those will work. You can't create list elements by assigning to the index, you have to use `array.append()`.

Comment: In general, no, looping through to set each item is not the fastest.  A few things though first: (1) what is `u`?  (2) How are you handling odd n?

Comment: BTW, `[]` creates a list, not an array. Python only has arrays in modules like `numpy`.

Comment: What is `i`, is it supposed to be the same as `index`?

Comment: Sorry "i" is supposed to be index; im supposed to use array.append; len(u) = n

Comment: What should the value be for `i = 0`?

Comment: Your requirements are very unclear. Nothing in the original requirements suggests the use of `mod`, but you use that in your attempted solution. It makes me think you don't understand how that operator works.

Comment: If you want to iterate from 1 to n, you need to use `range(1, n+1)`, since `range()` doesn't include the last value.

Comment: But your text says from 0 to n, not 1 to n. This question is really confusing, are you sure you understand the requirements? Perhaps you should show an actual example of the desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient way to construct such a collection, is with a numpy array.

We can construct this with:

```
import numpy as np

def generate_array(n):
    a = np.hstack((np.full(n//2+1, 2), np.zeros(n//2-1)))
    a[[0, n//2]] = 1
    return a
```

For example:

```
>>> generate_array(6)
array([1., 2., 2., 1., 0., 0.])
>>> generate_array(10)
array([1., 2., 2., 2., 2., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
>>> generate_array(16)
array([1., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
```

**Timings**:

for `n=100_000`, we get:

```
>>> timeit(partial(generate_array, 100_000), number=10_000)
1.0764452270013862
```

for `n=1_000_000`, we get:

```
>>> timeit(partial(generate_array, 1_000_000), number=1_000)
6.448311180000019
```

Generating an array of 100k elements, thus takes approximately (including small overhead of `partial`, etc.) *107.64 µs*, generating an array of 1M elements takes *6448.31µs*.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use `numpy` for this. You can use [`np.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) to concatenate multiple slices and use them to slice assign the array:

```
import numpy as np

n = 10
a = np.zeros(n)
a[np.r_[0,n//2]] = 1
a[np.r_[1:n//2]] = 2
a[np.r_[n//2+1:n]] = 0

print(a)
array([1., 2., 2., 2., 2., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
```

Comment: Shouldn't the first element be `0`?

Comment: No I think OPs `1` is the starting position (0) @bramar

Comment: It should be `[0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`

Comment: @Barmar, yatu: the specs do not define anything for the first element given it is zero-based, if it is one-based, the first element is 1.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes I assume the ifrst element is 1, also because the last is n, rather than n-1

Answer (score 1):

Since the other answers went with numpy arrays, which are pretty fast, I want to add some other answers for completeness. (There's obviously some ambiguity in the original question about what to do if n is odd and whether the author was expecting zero-based or one-based indexing.)

You can create a list pretty simply using a list comprehension

```
[1 if i in [0, n/2] else (2 if i <=(n/2) else 0) for i in range(0, n)]
```

But way quicker is extending the functionality of a list by extending the class:

```
class NewThing(list):
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
    def __getitem__(self,i):
        if i in {0,n/2}:
            return 1
        elif i <=n/2:
            return 2
        return 0
    def to_list(self):
        return [self[i] for i in range(0, n)]

>>>unique_list = NewThing(len(u))
>>>unique_list[4]
2
>>>unique_list.to_list()
[1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

You can call for the whole list, or just individual elements.  Creating the whole list is still slow.

Answer (score 1):

for even `n`:

```
def generate_array2(n):
    a = np.empty((2,n//2))
    a[0]=2
    a[1]=0
    a[:,0]=1
    return a.ravel()

%timeit a= generate_array2(1_000_000)
491 ± 6.58 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```